# How to fix "Android Resource linking failed"? using NavigationView and Fragments

Tags: java, android, hamburger-menu

**I want to use a burger-menu for my Android Studio application and I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer**

And in my `activity_main.xml` file i have this error:

```
Android resource linking failed 
E:\Smoozy\Documents\Findcontent\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:76:
 error: resource menu/drawer_view (aka com.example.findcontent:menu/drawer_view) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

**Here is my file directory:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd4Z9.jpg

My `drawer_view.xml` is in my layout folder and I tried removing "menu" from the `app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>` code statement.

```
 <!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code that is trying to reach it:

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on     nav item clicked
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new FirstFragment()).commit();

            break;
        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
            fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new SecondFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
            fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // Set action bar title
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    // Close the navigation drawer
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}

// ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to add `drawer_view` layout to `res/menu` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the "drawer_view.xml" file in the directory "menu" but you don"t have one. So just create, right click on res and then click on new -> new resource directory, select for resource type menu and press "ok".
Normaly you will see a menu folder now

Answer (score 0):

Go to res and right click New > Android Resources Directory ok
Named : **menu**
Go to drawable and cut the file 'drawer_view.xml' to **menu** folder
And change the path in code .
Hope to help You .

Comment: By this case **app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"**